# Is it possible to ceil the second floating point value in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, numpy

Ex:

`round(1.23,1) = 1.2,
math.ceil (1.23) = 2`

I want to ceil the second floating point to first flaoting point value like below
`1.23 = 1.3`

Comment: Not very elegant, but how about `math.ceil(x * 10) / 10`?

Comment: Thanks yours is very easy

Answer (score 1):

x=number , y=number of floating point

```
def ceil_round(x,y):
    z=math.ceil(x*(10**y))/(10**y)
    return(z)
```

ceil_round(1.334,2) gives 1.34